# Only last control in Data Template column getting updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, silverlight-4.0

I have a `DataTemplate` Column with 2 `DatePickers` that are bound to 2 properties. When the data in these control is changed only last control gets updated

```
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="300"  CanUserReorder="False" >              
         <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                 <Grid MouseRightButtonDown="ActionsGrid_MouseRightButtonDown" Width="300" Height="40" MouseLeftButtonDown="ActionsGrid_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                             <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" Text="{Binding Start,  Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"
                                         Padding="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                             <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100" Text="{Binding Due, Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"
                                         Padding="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                         </StackPanel>
                  </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>                                                  
          </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <sdk:DatePicker VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" SelectedDate="{Binding Start, Mode=TwoWay,}" Padding="2" />
                       <sdk:DatePicker VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" SelectedDate="{Binding Due, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  Padding="2" />
                     </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>  
     </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In this case if I update both Start and Due Only Due gets updated. Also the binding works fine because if I put a breakPoint on Start in my Model class it gets hit but the value passed is the original value of Start

**EDIT 1**

After some debugging I found out that If I only have one control inside my `DataTemplate` it works Fine. Also When I change the Date The break point is hit straightaway. But if I have more than one control the break point is not hit until I focus out of column and then only the last binding works.

**EDIT 2**

After some mroe debugging I noticed that it will work fine if I only use `CellTemplate` and discard cell `EditTemplate`

```
     <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="300"  CanUserReorder="False" >              
             <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <sdk:DatePicker VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" SelectedDate="{Binding Start, Mode=TwoWay,}" Padding="2" />
                       <sdk:DatePicker VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" SelectedDate="{Binding Due, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"  Padding="2" />
                  </StackPanel>
               </DataTemplate>  
     </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
   </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**EDIT 3**

```
private void DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (sender as DatePicker).GetBindingExpression(DatePicker.SelectedDateProperty).UpdateSource();
        }
```

I was able to refresh binding on both the control using the `selectedDatechange` event and then refreshing the binding on the sender.

I am still not sure why the 2 way binding working won't work.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

**EDIT 4**

Model and Properties

```
 public DateTime? Start 
        { 
            get { return _Start; } 
            set 
            { 
                _Start = value; Dirty = true; 

                if (_Start.HasValue && _Due.HasValue && _Start.Value > _Due.Value)
                    _dataErrors["Start"] = "Start date cannot be greater than the Due date";
                else
                    if (_dataErrors.ContainsKey("Start"))
                        _dataErrors.Remove("Start");
                NotifyPropertyChanged(); NotifyPropertyChanged("CalcStatus");
            } 
        }
        public DateTime? Due 
        { 
            get { return _Due; } 
            set 
            { 
                _Due = value; Dirty = true; 
                if (_Start.HasValue && _Due.HasValue && _Start.Value > _Due.Value)
                    _dataErrors["Start"] = "Start date cannot be greater than the Due date";
                else
                    if (_dataErrors.ContainsKey("Start"))
                        _dataErrors.Remove("Start");
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Due"); NotifyPropertyChanged("CalcStatus");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show the relevant viewmodel properties it is bound to. Are you properly implementing property changed notification?

Comment: Yes I am, The view model Implements the INotifyPropertyChanged Event and if I have only one control in the template its being hit no matter what property it's bound too. In case of more than one control only the last one gets Updated. The weird thing is that the NotifyPropertyChanged is called when I select another cell or column and then it only updates last control , the other properties are hit too but the value passed is same as existing value.

Comment: Why is there a WPF tag if this is Silverlight?  :) BTW is UpdateSourceTrigger PropertyChanged supported (or useful)?

Comment: What wpf tag? UpdateSourceTrigger PropertyChanged  is not supported because we are still using silverlight 4 due to client requirements.

Comment: ... It's also good practice to call NotifyPropertyChanged *immediately* after setting = value to its private member

Comment: There is a wpf tag on this question... that is not appropriate. That's why I opened it. I don't know Silverlight well, I've just read that someone simulated the update source trigger with behavior or attached property... Sorry, I can't help, bye

Comment: I wasn't getting any responses so I just added WPF tag as its xaml based too. I am actually simulating the  update source trigger with behavior with a event handler and everything is working fine. I just want to know why the properties are not getting updated with just the binding.

Comment: Don't you need `NotifyPropertyChanged("Start");` instead of `NotifyPropertyChanged();` in your Start setter ?

Comment: That is what was causing it but that wasn't a bug I was using [CallerMember] attribute with a default value so I didn't have to pass it PropertyName which was working fine except for dDataTemplate column. I'll explain more in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright I think I finally have fixed it. I am still not 100% sure why it wasnt working but I'll create a new small project and try to find out the reason.

What happened was that I modified my `NoitifyPropertyChangedEvent` by passing it`[CallerMemberName]` so that the name of the property calling it is passed automatically. Which means if I change the name property for example "Start" I don't have to worry about updating `NotifyPropertyChanged("Start")`.

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName =null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

This worked fine for all properties except for when I had a `DataTemplateColumn`. 
Converting it back to standard code and passing the propertyName explicitly fixed my issue.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```